# Is there a way to set promiscuous mode on mac through code?

Tags: macos, networking, wireshark

In wireshark, you can set the promiscuous mode to capture all packets. What is the underlying principle of the mac computer?

I want to set mac's promiscuous mode through code

Comment: Not all interfaces can be set to promiscuous. You need to determine if your particular interface has that capability.

Comment: @RonMaupin Hi there! How could I determine the capability of my NIC? Since this is a pretty short question I am going to use just a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done through [`pcap_open_live()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_live.3pcap.html) or [`pcap_set_promisc()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_set_promisc.3pcap.html), at least when using the libpcap library, which Wireshark does.

For more information and examples, visit https://www.tcpdump.org/index.html